# Whats wrong in this quicksort program?

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

I doubt that the there is something wrong with the partition function.

```
void swap(int num1, int num2) { /*function to swap the values */
   int temp = intArray[num1];    
   intArray[num1] = intArray[num2];
   intArray[num2] = temp;
}

int partition(int left, int right) { //partition function
   int leftPointer = left;
   int j;
   int pivot=intArray[right];
   for(j=0;j<right;j++){
    if(intArray[j]<=pivot){
        swap(j,leftPointer);
        leftPointer++;
    }
   }
  swap(leftPointer,right);
  return leftPointer;
}

void quickSort(int left, int right) { //quicksort
   if(left<right){
      int partitionPoint = partition(left, right);
      quickSort(left,partitionPoint-1);
      quickSort(partitionPoint+1,right);
   }
}
```

The program runs fine , but it doesn't sort!

Comment: Lol,i don't run it without main function, it's just the important part of the program

Comment: saying 'lol' doesn't make what you said funny or particularly helpful.

Comment: With due respect previous comment was deleted, so you are not aware of why I used LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your partition algorithm always starts at element zero. It should start at the start of the partition.

Comment: Thank you very much